# fingerprintjs2 to php variable

Tags: javascript, php, fingerprintjs2

I like to get fingerprint as php variable, I get the follow but do not want to work.

```
<p>fingerprint2: <strong id="fp2"></strong></p>

<script src="/fingerprintjs2/fingerprint2.js"></script>
<script>
    var fp2 = new Fingerprint2();
    fp2.get(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        $("#fp2").text(result);
    });
</script>

$myphpvar = "<script>document.write(fp2.get());</script>"; 

echo $myphpvar;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript is run after the PHP has completed. Client side VS server side code. I have solved this in the past by running the PHP within a PHP file that renders an image. This method is often referred to pixel tracking.

Here are the basics, you need to pass your variables in Javascript to a PHP file that renders an image:

```
document.write("<img src=fingerprint.php?x="+x+"&y="+y+" width=1 height=1>");
```

In the above case it passed Javascript variables x and y to the PHP image.

Then the fingerprint.php script looks like:

```
    <?php
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    session_start();

    $x = $_REQUEST['x'];
    $y = $_REQUEST['y'];

    $_SESSION['x'] = $x;
    $_SESSION['y'] = $y              

    // SHOW THE IMAGE
    $im      = imagecreatefrompng("fingerprint.png");

    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);

    ?>
```

The png image can be anything you want as it will just be a 1 x 1 image on your final screen. You now have the Javascript variables in your PHP. As the code starts a session you could write the variables to a session and collect them later in another script, or write them to a database and recover later. Try with my simple example to ensure you have it working then expand from there.

Comment: If you had more rep, I would downvote this. There's rarely a good reason to use document.write and in this scenario it requires the blocking download and execution of a complex bit of JavaScript before it executes.

Answer (score 0):

That's really not how PHP works at all. PHP cannot process client side JavaScript. If you want access to client side information in PHP then you should probably put it in a form and post it to another page in PHP. There are many good tutorials on PHP forms, such as [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp).

Comment: yes I know, it's possible send an POST but don't like in this way to send it over the network.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways you can send data from JavaScript back serverside

- set a cookie and read it in the next request
- request further content by injecting a script / IMG / iframe tag (but not using document.write) adding the fingerprint in the query of the url
- make an AJAX request
- add a hidden input to a form on the page - requires the user to navigate out of the page using the form